# Como estilizar o campo onde fica os options de um tag select?

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme a foto anterior mostra, eu gostaria de estilizar aquele local que está demarcado em vermelho.

Ja coloquei o seguinte código:

```
select option {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

O `background-color` funcionou, porém o atributo `border` não funcionou e varios outros atributos também não funcionaram.
Eu gostaria de estilizar um `<select>` de forma parecida com o `<select class="selectpicker">` do Bootstrap, porém os atributos que eu coloco não são reconhecidos (parece). Alguém saberia porque não estão funcionando/sendo reconhecidos?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como foi dito existe um limite até onde você poderá customizar o SELECT, mas pra casos como esse existe o Bootstrap. Recomento da uma lida na documentação deles [Introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/).

Segue um pequeno exemplo que modifiquei:

[Customizando o Select com o Bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/Ghost4090/pfoxrfz7/3/)

Pra fazer rodar você irá precisar dos arquivos do Bootstrap que se encontrão na aba **External Resources** no site desse link.

Answer (score 0):

É quase impossível estilizar `options` de forma livre, cada navegador entende sua estilização de forma diferente, além disso ele aceita poucas propriedades de estilo, a solução adotada por frameworks de UI como...

[mdBooststrap select menus](https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/material-select/)

[Jquery UI select menus](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/)

É a substituição dos `selects` para `ul´s` e `li´s` após o carregamento da página, mantendo a função do mesmo em formulários.

Também pode ser feito manualmente com [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Answer (score 0):

Existem muitas limitações com a estilização de select, entretanto você pode brincar com as propriedades.

Pra alterar a borda use o outline, não o border.

Se quiser ter mais liberdade, como mudar o hover de option, vai ter que usar alguma library como [select2](https://select2.org/) ou choosen.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kr5s2pp6/)**